# Get dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS From YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ Date format In Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS From YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ**

I am trying to print date in mm/dd/yyyy format.

**{{"2016-03-16T18:19:48.210Z" | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}**

**output:**  03/16/2016 at 11:49PM
       which should be **03/16/2016 at 06:19 PM**

How do i find desired output in Angular Js.
       please help me.

Comment: `2016-03-16T18:19:48.210Z` is a local date (depending on which timezone your machine is set).

Comment: Indeed, I see what you are asking now. Use the [3rd parameter Timezone](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Answer (score 0):

Install [Angular i18n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

> The Angular datetime filter uses the time zone settings of the
>   browser. The same application will show different time information
>   depending on the time zone settings of the computer that the
>   application is running on. Neither JavaScript nor Angular currently
>   supports displaying the date with a timezone specified by the
>   developer.

**npm**

```
npm install angular-i18n
```

Add a `<script>` to your index.html:

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_YOUR-LOCALE.js"></script>
```

Note that this package is not in CommonJS format, so doing require('angular-i18n') will return undefined.

**bower**

```
bower install angular-i18n
```

Add a `<script>` to your index.html:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_YOUR-LOCALE.js"></script>
```